# The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed error

Tags: vb.net, designer, partial-classes

This code compiles and runs fine, but I get the error: "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed".  Basically the designer does not work. I'm making a class library with shared forms within a class. Is there a way to help the designer understand what needs to be done here? Here is all the code:

```
Module MainMod
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim cls As New Class1
        cls.ShowForm()
    End Sub
End Module

Partial Public Class Class1
    Public var As String = ""

    Public Sub ShowForm()
        Dim frm As New Form1
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

Partial Public Class Class1
    Public Class Form1

    End Class
End Class
Partial Public Class Class1
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
    Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.Text = "Form1"
    End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Move everything above Class1 to the bottom of the file.  It is *strongly* recommended to the use Form project template to get this right consistently.  Project + Add New Item.

Comment: @Hans True I was hoping there was a way around that.  The real problem is that the only things visible in a class library are classes.  So my solution was to encapsulate everything in a class so I could access my public variables like (eg. String UserName = "Bob").  All the forms need to know who the user is within the class library and outside it.  I tried declaring Public Username in the module but I couldn't see it even after Import ClassLibrary unless it was in a class.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the designer to work, the designer generated partial class must be stored in a separate `.Designer.vb` file and the main class (for the code-behind) must be the first class declared in the file.  Consequently, in order for them to work with the designer, each form must have it's own set of `FormName.vb` and `FormName.Designer.vb` files.